# How delete image by Uri using scoped storage android 10?

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

How I can delete image by Uri using scoped storage android 10?

I saved my images to this scoped

```
final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "myApp" + File.separator + constants.PhotoDirName;
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
```

I need to delete an image using Uri using this code

```
String[] projection;
projection = new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID};
Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(externalUri, projection,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[]{displayName}, null);
assert cursor != null;
cursor.moveToFirst();

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    long fileId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    cursor.close();
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(externalUri.toString() + "/" + fileId);

if (uri != null) {
        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{displayName};

        try {
            resolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", selectionArgsPdf);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // show some alert message
        }
    }
}
```

But the image did not deleted!!

this error appears

```
android.app.RecoverableSecurityException: com.xxxx.xxxx has no access to content://media/external/images/media/11774
```

Comment: did you found the answer?